# Identifying the model of LCD for replacement for temperature sensor

Tags: lcd

I want to replace a broken LCD with a rubber zebra connector in a "cheap" temperature sensor. There is no model or any data on the screen nor on the PCB. I'm looking for a replacement part. How can I identify it?

**UPDATE**

So my initial question was beginner and optimistic. I should have asked (myself) if the LCD is custom-made or not. Cuz custom-made is unlikely to be sold. I received two answered, both indicating that such a screen is custom made (the emoji was the best clue for that). So I would like to accept one of the answers.

I attached photos of the broken and working one too:
Broken display:

[image]

Operational display:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 99.8% for sure a custom display with that smiley face, so any replacement would almost surely have to come from a cannibalized unit or from the manufacturer (not likely).

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely rare to find aftermarket replacements for custom LCDs.

I have found ones for a specific model of marine navigation equipment, at over $50 each LCD. I'm not sure if they were ex-factory, or somebody thought it was worthwhile to reverse-engineer and pay to have a batch made up for all the Autohelm users out there.

For anything else your only hope is to buy an identical unit and cannibalise it for a spare display.